# WordPress pagination 404 error

Tags: wordpress

i am using WordPress paginate_links() function in my custom template but the problem is when ever i go to page 2 the page stucks and it gives 404 error in console. My custom query is

```
     if( get_query_var( 'paged' )){
                    $paged_documents =  get_query_var( 'paged' );
                }
                else if( get_query_var( 'page' )){
                    $paged_documents =  get_query_var( 'page' );
                }
                else{
                    $paged_documents =  1;
                }
                $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'documents', 'posts_per_page' => 8,'paged'=>$paged_documents) );
```

My permalink is set to Post name.

I have already found two solutions.
1) Change permalink settings to "Plain". Which i dont want to.
2) Page name and url must be different from custom post type. For Example in above snippet post_type is document as well as page name and url. I dont want to change the page name and urls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

```
<?php
wp_reset_query();
$paged_documents  = get_query_var('paged', 1);

$query = array(
        'post_type' => 'documents',
        'posts_per_page' => '8',
        'paged' => $paged_documents
      );
?>
```